# Minecraft NBT zlib compression in c doesn't get accepted by the game

Tags: c++, compression, zlib, minecraft

I'm currently working on a NBT reader and writer to edit Minecraft maps (both the player data and the chunks themselves). I've got the reading of NBTData all done and I was able to write a level.dat file to edit some player data.

Unfortunately I am still unable to write my NBT binary data to a region file because Minecraft isn't accepting my compression method. Whenever I try to load in my edited chunks it gives me the error that it couldn't find the end of the ZLib compression or that it's a invalid compression method (I caught these error by launching minecraft via the Terminal).

I am using the ZLib library that comes with Mac OSX and the editor is written in C++.

Here's my compression code:

```
compressionData* compress(unsigned char* buf, int size)
{
    vector<char> data = vector<char>();
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
        data.push_back(buf[i]);

    int ret;
    z_stream zs;
    char buff[4096];
    std::vector<char> out_data;

    // initialize zlib structure
    memset(&zs, 0, sizeof(zs));
    if(deflateInit(&zs, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION) != Z_OK)
        return false;
    zs.next_in = (Bytef *) data.data();
    zs.avail_in = data.size();

    // deflate blocks
    do {
        zs.next_out = reinterpret_cast<Bytef *>(buff);
        zs.avail_out = 4096;

        // deflate data and place in out_data
        ret = deflate(&zs, Z_FINISH);
        out_data.insert(out_data.end(), buff, buff + zs.total_out);
    } while(ret == Z_OK);

    // check for errors
    deflateEnd(&zs);
    if (ret != Z_STREAM_END)
        return false;

    // assign to data
    data = out_data;

    compressionData *rett = new compressionData();
    rett->buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(data.size());
    SharedStats::getSharedStats()->mallocated++;
    for(int i = 0;i<data.size();i++)
        rett->buf[i] = data.at(i);

    rett->size = (int)data.size();

    return rett;
}
```

The compressionData object is a struct that only holds a unsigned char array containing the data and a int saying how long the data is in bytes.

What method of ZLib encryption should I use for the Minecraft Chunks? The original input chunks always start with these three bytes: 02 78 9C, my chunks start with 02 78 DA.

All the data from the chunks is written in a region file and Minecraft does recognise them, it just doesn't like the compression method.

Greats,
Allan

Answer (score 2):

This `out_data.insert(out_data.end(), buff, buff + zs.total_out);` appears to be incorrect.  The `total_out` field is the total amount of data generated by all of the `deflate()` calls, not the one call just made.  The number of bytes actually in `buff` is `4096 - zs.avail_out`.

The `78 9c` and `78 da` are both valid zlib headers.  They only differ in identifying the compression level used, which is inconsequential for decompression.

I don't know where the `02` is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The `02` in front of the zlib header bytes are the compression type.

- 1 => gzip
- 2 => zlib
- 3 => uncompressed

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the question. Also, it's better to leave source link to such information. Here I could find only [this](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Region_file_format) fandom wiki and nothing more official.